# Mac - External hard drive backups

Tags: mac, backup, external-hard-drive

I have two external hard drives, WD 320GB and a WD 1TB.

I would like to backup my WD 320GB on a regular basis. Please could you inform me of a good application which could provide these needs:

- Backup compression (not just copy and
  pasting the files)
- Support for FAT-32
- Possibly scheduling

The external hard drives are in a FAT-32 format because they are sometimes used on a Windows computer.

I have used Get Backup and it doesn't seem to work, as it has an error about copying files with the same name but different extensions

Comment: Get a real backup disk. And skip the compression -- it's far better in the long run to do incremental backups.

Answer (score 0):

SuperDuper! or Carbon Copy Cloner are the best Mac backup apps. However, neither does compression. (I don't know of any app that does do backup compression.)

Comment: Thanks, SuperDuper doesn't allow me to select external drives for the source. And CCC doesn't support drives that are not HFS+.

Comment: SuperDuper! definitely allows the selection of external drives as the source. I regularly back up my external music drive to another external. Maybe source drives need to be HFS+, but that's a bit strange. SuperDuper! just uses rsync in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

[SilverKeeper](http://www.lacie.com/silverkeeper/) from LaCie is very flexible.

Although like SuperDuper and CCC it does NOT do compression.